# MySQL Column Subquery Using Dynamic Table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm not sure exactly what this is called, a dynamic subquery perhaps? I'm trying to pull information from a related table depending on what exists in a certain column. In this case, it's column `Page`.`type` and ideally i'd like CONCAT that with a string to create the table name and then query that table.

Is there any way to do such a subquery? Perhaps I need to nest this subquery as a LEFT JOIN instead.

Alternatively, can this type of dynamic behavior only be accomplished exclusively as a stored procedure?

The key is we have various types of meta data associated with our SiteManagerPage. This data is unique in type and column structure, hence this way of doing it versus normalizing the tables differently.

Relationships:

[image]

```
Page.id (1:n) SiteManagerPage.page_id

SiteManagerPage.meta_page_id (1:1) meta_{Page.type}.id
```

Query:

```
SELECT `Page`.`id`, `Page`.`label`, `Page`.`type`,
    (SELECT `title` FROM CONCAT('meta_', `Page`.`type`) 
     WHERE 'id'=`SiteManagerPage`.`meta_page_id`) as `meta_title`
FROM `pages` AS `Page` 
 INNER JOIN `site_manager_pages` AS `SiteManagerPage` ON (`SiteManagerPage`.`page_id` = `Page`.`id` AND `SiteManagerPage`.`link_id` = '50f9b98d-4004-42f1-ab05-14133238f442' AND `hidden` = '0') 
 INNER JOIN `plan_page_tags` AS `PlanPageTag` ON (`PlanPageTag`.`page_id` = `Page`.`id` AND `plan_package_id` = '50b83acd-b060-45fc-a8cc-3feb3238f442') 
WHERE 1 = 1 
ORDER BY `sortable` ASC, `SiteManagerPage`.`order` ASC,
         `PlanPageTag`.`order` ASC
```

Comment: Do the possible tables come from a small, predefined set of tables? If not, you'll have to use a dynamic query in a stored procedure.

Comment: The possible tables are pre-existing, yes. Maybe i'm not thinking clearly...how exactly does that help the situation?

Comment: You could join with all of them, and then use a CASE statement to select the appropriate one to return in the SELECT>